# Is <main><footer></footer></main> valid?

Tags: html

Simple question, big arguments.. is the following example valid code? ([other code] stands for the other valid code in the page)

```
<main> [other code] <footer></footer></main>
```

Comment: If you mean "valid" in the traditional sense then http://validator.nu will tell you. If you mean "valid" as in semantically sound, then yes, because there's nothing stopping the main content from having a footer of its own (although note that the main element itself does not create a section).

Answer (score 0):

This is nested, like any other HTML tags. So yes, it's totally valid. Now, if you are running old browsers, it may go through invalid tags because they are from HTML5 and do a mess with your web without an HTML5 conversor for those old browsers.